# Regex matching area in PHP

Tags: php, regex

So I am doing a bit of scraping on a site, and everything is working just fine. The results I get back from the page have some span tags like such:

```
<span id="content_drptrResults_lblStatus_0">Assigned</span>
```

There are actually a possible 5 span tags that could be returned. From 0-4. I'd like to be able to get the status dug out between the opening and closing span tags. I can't seem to find something on SO that works for what I need.

Comment: maybe better use an xpath instead of regex

Comment: Nope, don't go with regex , use a **DOMDocument** class ,  `foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('span') as $tag) {
               echo $tag->nodeValue;
    }`

Comment: so what about using preg_match_all?

Comment: Are you looking to scrape content_drptrResults_lbl`Status_0` from the id atrib?

Comment: yes, there are 5 possibilities from "Status_0" to "Status_4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex. But if you have to, this is far from perfect.
Its especially bad if nesting occurs.

```
 #  '/<span(?=\s)[^>]*id\s*=\s*"[^"]*Status_([0-4])[^"]*"[^>]*>([^<>]*)<\/span\s*>/'


 <span
 (?= \s )
 [^>]* 
 id \s* = \s* 
 " [^"]* 
 Status_
 ( [0-4] )        # (1)
 [^"]* 
 "
 [^>]* 
 >  
 ( [^<>]* )       # (2)
 </span \s* >
```

Perl test case

```
$str = '<span id="content_drptrResults_lblStatus_0">Assigned</span>';

if ($str  =~ /<span(?=\s)[^>]*id\s*=\s*"[^"]*Status_([0-4])[^"]*"[^>]*>([^<>]*)<\/span\s*>/)
{
    print "Matched '$1' = '$2'\n";
}
```

Output >>

```
Matched '0' = 'Assigned'
```

Comment: grrr - I can't get this to work.

Comment: @MrTechie - Should work. I changed the delimiter and added a test case in Perl (don't have php), same as PCRE.

Comment: I got it working after a little tweaking but you put me on the right path! :) Thanks